# Flutter Listview Data Sync

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to listen for updates of items in listview. For example, I list my news in listview.  When I open the news details page and add the news back to favorites, it is not seen in the listview that the news are in the favorites. Because the data was not renewed. I don't want to retrieve the data from the server again. How can I solve it to be the best performing? Listening etc.

Comment: 1st of all it depends on your code structure. 
try use BlocLibray or Providers to handle states.

Comment: @Mateen I use the bloc structure to fetch news from the server. But I'm not sure of the result of using this structure for every listview item.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a database for favorites? You can use StreamBuilder with Stream data from your database, I don't know what's your database type but I am using floor(it's working with sqflite) and there is a query method like below;

```
@Query('SELECT * FROM Person')
Stream<List<Person>> findAllPersonsAsStream();
```

When I use findAllPersonsAsStream() as "stream:" in a stream builder list updated itself immediately when add or remove something in favorite list.

Edit: If you are using Bloc and Sqflite, check [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/using-streams-blocs-and-sqlite-in-flutter-2e59e1f7cdce/) for detailed explanation.